# Need a Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE)

Tags: regex, pcre

Hi can someone please help me in writing this regex. I need to search twitter tweets for tweets having (tickets or tix) AND (sale or low).

I know I can use this `/(tickets|tix)(sale|low)/i`

But how to do the AND part.

Comment: When you say "AND", do you mean that the tweet must contain the word AND, or something else?

Comment: Could `sale|low` come before `tickets|tix`, or will it always come after?

Comment: it could be any order actually @Wiseguy ... AND means the operator AND p.g.l.hall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's already the AND part, but I guess you want those words to appear anywhere. This should do it:

```
/.*(tickets|tix).*(sale|low).*/i
```

This should do it, but (tickets|tix) MUST appear BEFORE (sale|low). If you don't want them in that order, you can use 2 different regexes for each tweet:

```
/(tickets|tix)/i
/(sale|low)/i
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
/[tickets|tix][sale|low]/i
```

Comment: This will match strings that have tickets/tix **OR** sale/low

Comment: It's even worse than that.  It matches exactly two characters: one from the set `{ 't' 'i' 'c' 'k' 'e' 's' 'x' '|' }` followed by one from the set `{ 's' 'a' 'l' 'e' 'o' 'w' '|' }` (or the uppercase equivalents, in the case of the letters). [ref](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)